# Laravel localization, hyphen and underscore

Tags: laravel

What kind of locale do you use in: url, foldername, database??

There are two kinds of localization.

**1. url localization**

```
  en-us  
  zh-tw
```

I use mcamara/laravel-localization

**2. content localization**
Like product names in different language. I use Astrotomic/laravel-translatable, and it requires a locale column in translation table.

product_translations:

```
id locale product_id   name
1   en-us    1         iphone
2   zh-tw    1         蘋果手機
```

This is not ok:

```
languages table  
id, locale, name
1 en-us English
2 zh-tw Taiwan

product_translations
id language_id product_id name
1   1           1         iphone
2   2           1         蘋果手機
```

"locale" column must exist in the translation table.

In product's OptionController, I want make option translations for blade.

```
    if($option->translations->isEmpty()){
        $option_translations = [];
    }else{
        foreach ($option->translations as $translation) {
            $locale = str_replace('-', '_', $translation->locale);
            //$option_translations->$locale = $translation->toArray();
            $option_translations[$locale] = $translation->toArray();
        }
    }
```

This caused an error. Because hyphen cannot be the variable name. So, en-us cannot be the $option_translations->$locale

I have to add the replace codes everywhere when doing the translation.

```
$locale = str_replace('-', '_', $locale);
or  
$locale = str_replace('_', '-', $locale);
```

---

- The laravel docs suggests underscore.

> according to the ISO 15897. For example, "en_GB" should be used for
> British English rather than "en-gb".

- The mcamara/laravel-localization package use hyphen in config file: config\laravellocalization.php
  And this will map to folder name. Although it has localesMapping parameter.
- Hyphen seems to be more common in url, like Microsoft's website:
  https://www.microsoft.com/zh-tw

So, what kind of locale do you use in: url, foldername, database??

Comment: what variable is being attempted to be named with a hyphen?

Comment: $locale in the foreach()

Comment: that isn't being named, that is just setting the value of the `$locale` variable ... that variable is named 'locale'

Comment: You Got The Point! Ok, it's before blade. I modified the question.

Comment: Maybe for() is another way. But I think not better.

Comment: Always is good way to have all prepared variables and values programatically. Being said, I'd have en_us stored in DB and just for needs of output I'd have an accessor that converts DB value to what should be seen/output (i.e. en-us). So, only at last step (output to user/visitor value should be converted; in all steps before it should be used how is considered best for programming).

Comment: Also, you can have [strings with hyphens as array keys](https://3v4l.org/XMEJW). Maybe something with literals/missing quotes?

Comment: there is no variable being named with a hyphen ... variables can hold strings, strings can have hyphens ... array keys can be strings which means they can have hyphens

Comment: What kind do you use to store in database? Like product_translation's "locale" column.  en-US or en_US ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my solution is

- In database, use en_GB, zh_Hant
- lang folder name, use eg_GB, zh_Hant
- config\app.php

  locale => zh_Hant
- In config file "config\laravellocalization.php" of package mcamara/laravel-localization, default "supportedLocales" array is hyphen, change to underscore en_GB,

  ```
   'supportedLocales' => [
       ...
       'en_GB'       => ['name' => 'British English', ...
       ...
       'zh_Hant'     => ['name' => ...
   ]
  ```

and "localesMapping" array add

```
'localesMapping' => [
    'zh_Hant' => 'zh-Hant'
],
```

So the url is en-GB, like http://example.com/en-GB. And all codes in the project are en_GB. Because the package mcamara/laravel-localization will do the mapping.

If I use

```
App::getLocale()
```

I will get "en_GB", not the url's "en-GB"

Then $product_translations can be

```
foreach($product_translations as $product_translation){
    ...
    $product_translation->$locale = ...
    ...
}
```

It will be

```
$product_translation->en_GB
$product_translation->zh_TW
...
```

We don't need to do any str_replace();